# Using execlp() and experiencing pointer related warnings

Tags: c, pointers, posix

I'm trying to use execlp(), but keep getting warnings that I'm not sure how to fix

pathPiece is an array of paths to attempt to use in order to find the command.
pathNum is the number of paths there are to try.

```
void execute(const char *argv, char *path, int argNum, const char **pathPiece, int pathNum){
  int i, ret;
  for(i = 0; i < pathNum; i++)
    if(argNum == 0){
      ret = execlp((const char *)&pathPiece[i], (const char *)argv[0], (const char*)NULL);
    if(ret == -1)
      continue;
    else{
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size

Comment: Please also indicate which line it is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pathPiece is `const char *pathPiece`, so pathPiece[i] is a single char. From your description, it sounds like you want pathPiece to be a `const char **` instead.

Comment: That's true, so for every instance where I currently have pathPiece would I change it to *pathPiece and everywhere I currently have *pathPiece should become **pathPiece?

Comment: In this function, you should only change the `const char *pathPiece` in the argument list to `const char **pathPiece`. `pathPiece[i]` is then correct as-is. I couldn't say what to do in other parts of your code, as I don't know what it looks like.

Comment: True, thanks for the help.  I updated the other parts and now I'm only getting the warning about "cast to pointer from integer of different size".  I'm not sure what that really means and a google search didn't bring up too much.

Answer (score 1):

Does using: (const char *)&pathPiece[i] work for you?

Comment: It gets rid of the second warning, but the first one stays there.  Why would accessing the address of pathPiece fix that warning?  As Anomie pointed out also it should be a char**.

Comment: The second parameter is argv[0] which is a char, so it should be:  (const char *)&argv[0] or just argv.

Answer (score 1):

since `pathPiece` is `const char **`, `pathPiece[i]` will be of type `const char *`, and `&pathPiece[i]` will be of type `const char **`. Passing that type to execlp is wrong and causes undefined behavior.